# Multiple selection dropdown list

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I need to set a dropdown list with multiple selection. As my application don't have a `MenuBar` and I can't use a `Menu` with multiple `CheckMenuItem`, I thought about using `ComboBox` or `ChoiceBox` as solution, but it seems that none of them have this option. Is using the `ControlsFX CheckComboBox` the only way to perform that?

I'd rather to use native JavaFX libraries

Comment: How about a [`MenuButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) with `CheckMenuItem`s?

Comment: It seems that's the way to go, thanks!